# Picking from Logistic vs Survival Model

Tags: regression, logistic, survival, censoring, tobit-regression

I have a health data set for measuring the effectiveness of a drug. (Age, Gender(0,1), Morbidity(1,2,3), Dosage(0,1), Group (a,b), Effect (Not effective =0, effective = 1), and Time (days needed for drug to work if Effect = 1, Days observed until subject left the study if Effect =0), and I'm being asked to predict Effect.

Obviously, Time is better if it's lower. My general recollection with survival models using right censored data is that "longer" or "bigger" Time is better. (I'm remembering my GLM class from 2005 in undergrad.)

Should I be using Logistic Regression or a Survival Model? Are there other types I should consider?

If I were to be predicting Time, would a linear regression model or a Tobit model be appropriate?

Thank you in advance for any help. I've hosted my data [here](https://nofile.io/f/nMao7hxwtBz/ares_data_set.xlsx) if anyone wants to poke at it.

Comment: Survival analysis is your choice given "subject left study" has no relation with "drug to work".

Answer (score 3):

First, whether longer is better or worse does not depend on your choice of model but on what is being measured. One common use of *survival* analysis (and the reason for its name) is time to death. Obviously, longer is better! But if your effect is good (e.g. relapse from a disease) then longer is worse. That's not a problem. Survival analysis can be used in both cases.

Second, logistic and survival analysis ask different questions. Logistic, in your case, would answer "Was the probability of an effect related to age, gender etc.?" while survival would answer "Was the time to the effect (technically, the instantaneous hazard) related to age, gender etc.?"

Does time to effect matter a lot in your study?

Third, if you are predicting time then you want survival analysis, not linear or tobit. The great strength of survival analysis is that it deals well with censoring - those people who left the study for whom you have only the information that the effect did not occur before they left.

Comment: Hi Peter, this is very helpful. I need to do two sets of analysis, one to predict effect, and another to predict time to effectiveness. The former will be logistic and the latter survival, based on what you've said. QUESTION: Is using right censored data as a predictor problematic? I've found some papers online suggesting that it causes parameter inflation in *linear* regression models, but haven't found anything relating to logistic regression.

Comment: Ummm.... None of your predictors will be right censored.

Comment: Peter, isn't my Time variable right censored? restated: Time (days needed for drug to work if Effect = 1, Days observed until subject left the study if Effect =0)

Comment: Yes, but it should not be a predictor in the logistic regression.

Comment: Interesting...! It's actually one of the most powerful predictors in the dataset. Why should it not be used is a predictor?

Comment: If you want to poke at my data it's hosted here: https://nofile.io/f/nMao7hxwtBz/ares_data_set.xlsx

Comment: For one thing, you don't know it when you start. 

Of course it's highly related to the event, but it's not a predictor because it doesn't come first.

Comment: Peter, very good point and fascinating. And of as you mentioned previously, survival analysis will evaluate what predicts the time to effectiveness. What the data shows is that IF the drug is effective, the average Time is very short. If the drug is inneffective,the time is very long.